# Update data in original table from view

Tags: oracle, view, oracle-apex

I have a table where an update is required in only column, it is just a flag to update.

But I have to show details from other table as well, that is only for display.

```
    Table1:
    emp_id
    emp_name....
    emp_status (will be updated via tabular forms)

    Table2:
    emp_bank_id
    emp_bank_account
    ....
```

The records should be displayed in a report format and update the emp_status value to '1' (previously 0)  where user has ticked the check-box, so multiple records will be updated

Can I create a view and then chose to update only this column using tabular form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create the Tabular Form using the 2 tables without a view as long as only one of the tables is being updated.

Just create your Tabular Form choosing the table you need to update and then change the query to include the columns from the other table and change all the column from the included table to **Plain Text**.

If you prefer to use a view you should create an **instead of trigger**, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER iof_MY_TRIGGER
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
ON v_tbls
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  UPDATE table1 
     SET emp_status = :NEW.EMP_STATUS
   WHERE emp_id = :NEW.EMP_ID;

END iof_MY_TRIGGER;
/
```

To include a checkbox to your tabular form change your tabular form for something like this:

```
SELECT emp_id
,      emp_name
,      apex_item.checkbox2(5, emp_status, DECODE(emp_status, 1,'CHECKED',0))
  FROM table1
```

You can read more about this in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_item.htm#AEAPI193)

Comment: Thanks buddy, I have started with a single table, it is now showing the records, only one column is set to update, rest are displayed as text. Now I want that if a check box is checked, save 1 else save 0 in column.

Comment: Edited my response to include how you can create a checkbox in the tabular form.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your updated solution, but it didn't work for me. Instead just, marked the status as update-able, set the field as check box and under List of Values for this column, added 1,0. And it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me was, set the field as `editable`, leaving the rest to be displayed as plain text in report.

Double click on the column under the tabular report region which you want to edit, set the field type as `Simple Checkbox` for title `Display as` under the section `Column Attributes`

Now, on same page under `List of Values`, enter `1,0`

1=> Checked

0=> Unchecked

And that is all one need.